# How can I retrieve the native message ID of a Spring Cloud Stream Message?

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream

I'm looking to get the native message identifier for a `Message` that I received from GCP Pub/Sub through Spring Cloud Stream.

I see that there's an identifier in `Message` that Spring Cloud Stream sets:

```
/**
 * The key for the Message ID. This is an automatically generated UUID and
 * should never be explicitly set in the header map <b>except</b> in the
 * case of Message deserialization where the serialized Message's generated
 * UUID is being restored.
 */
public static final String ID = "id";
```

However, I'm looking for the *native* message identifier -- the one that GCP Pub/Sub (or another service, for instance) would set. Ideally I'd like to be able to use the same approach irrespective of where my message is going and stay agnostic. Where's the right place to look, if there is one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you can have a completely agnostic solution - kafka has no concept of a native message id, for example.

`id` is reserved (by spring-messaging).

It looks like the pub/sub adapter has a header mapper that maps all inbound headers, by default.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/7e6f1b9e14740edeeae7b7c7b377980727d49d66/spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spring/pubsub/integration/PubSubHeaderMapper.java#L61

If the native header is something other than `id`, it will be mapped.

The inbound channel adapter supports using a custom mapper (which could map a native `id` to something else), but it doesn't look like the binder currently supports configuring a custom mapper into the adapter.

Comment: I just looked at it some more and this looks interesting: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/7e6f1b9e14740edeeae7b7c7b377980727d49d66/spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spring/pubsub/integration/inbound/PubSubInboundChannelAdapter.java#L126 - the raw pubsub message is available in a header, so you should be able to get the `messageId` property using that header - `rawMessage.getPubSubMessage().getMessageId()`.